# Android activity over lock screen

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen, powermanager

I need help with my project , I'm supposed to make a BroadcastReceiver fires up a full screen activity over current lock screen .
I tried this on my activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("onCreate","success");
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
    wakeLock.acquire(10*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/);
    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    this.setShowWhenLocked(true);
    this.setTurnScreenOn(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop);
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,StopTheAlarm.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".Stop"
         android:showOnLockScreen="true"
         android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
</activity>
```

but it doesn't work on my android 7.0.1 phone

Comment: is it working on other android versions? Might be the issue of your broadcast receiver not been registered in the manifest.

Comment: it is registered the BroadcastReceiver works fine
i did not try other versions due to lack of resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update :
i removed

```
this.setShowWhenLocked(true);
this.setTurnScreenOn(true);
```

which were causing app to crash

Answer (score 0):

Your solution won't work on Android API 27 and later. Use code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643424/what-to-use-instead-of-deprecated-flag-show-when-locked-flag-to-start-activity-w).